# How can I search a pandas dataframe to fill in another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have data in the form :

```
President             Years    Executive Orders
George Washington   1789-1797        8
John Adams          1797-1801        1
Thomas Jefferson    1801-1809        4
                ...
```

The years are in string format and I would like to create a new dataframe in which each year is resampled like below so that i could create a plot of executive orders through the years (I would interpolate because the data doesn't give data between 1801-1809 for example):

```
Year  Executive Orders
1789         8
1790         0
1791         0
...
```

Basically I'd like to do like a lookup for a date in the 2nd df in the 1st df and see how many orders . Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from io import StringIO

data = '''\
President             Years    Executive Orders
George Washington   1789-1797        8
John Adams          1797-1801        1
Thomas Jefferson    1801-1809        4
'''
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep=r'\s+')

df[['From', 'To']] = df['Executive'].str.split('-', expand=True)
df['From'] = pd.to_datetime(df['From'])
df['To'] = pd.to_datetime(df['To'])

df_orders = df[['Orders', 'From']].set_index('From')
```

This results in the following DataFrame

```
            Orders
From              
1789-01-01       8
1797-01-01       1
1801-01-01       4
```

Since the index column is a date column `resample` can be used to resample data as needed. See the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#offset-aliases) for how data can be resampled.

```
df_orders_resampled = df_orders.resample('AS').sum().fillna(0)

            Orders
From              
1789-01-01     8.0
1790-01-01     0.0
1791-01-01     0.0
1792-01-01     0.0
1793-01-01     0.0
1794-01-01     0.0
1795-01-01     0.0
1796-01-01     0.0
1797-01-01     1.0
1798-01-01     0.0
1799-01-01     0.0
1800-01-01     0.0
1801-01-01     4.0

df_orders_resampled.plot()
```

[image: plot]